# JPA Hibernate : Help with classic Batching Insert values (...),(...),(...)

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, batch-processing

I've read the forum/searched high and low but this will just not batch as I would expect.
In short I want Insert into timeseries values (...), (...), (...)  to batch up the insert into one statement.

Postgres 9.
Hibernate 3.4.0.
JPA 1.99

The entity has no relationships to other entities / collections, it is all by itself it is versioned, and uses GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Here is what the internet says should activate this feature.

In Java, Inside my @Transactional, I call .merge on that type of entity and only that type. I've also tried calling persist, and disabling versioning… no luck… 
I note this in the logs: AbstractBatcher: - no batched statements to execute

Any help?

---

Here is some relevant debug trace… reduced for simplicity...

2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - transient instance of: com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] DefaultPersistEventListener: - saving transient instance
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - generated identifier: 188032722, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - saving [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032722]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] Versioning: - using initial version: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - flushing session
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - processing flush-time cascades
//snip

2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] Cascade: - processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity
2011-03-31 14:20:37,414 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] Cascade: - done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity
//snip

2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - dirty checking collections
2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity.highestValidDataStartTime is dirty
2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity.seriesEndTime is dirty
2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity.seriesStartTime is dirty
2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] DefaultFlushEntityEventListener: - Updating entity: [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032673]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,415 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] Versioning: - Incrementing: 0 to 1
//snip

2011-03-31 14:20:37,418 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - Processing unreferenced collections
2011-03-31 14:20:37,418 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
2011-03-31 14:20:37,418 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - Flushed: 50 insertions, 50 updates, 0 deletions to 50 objects
2011-03-31 14:20:37,418 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
//snip

2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - executing flush
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] ConnectionManager: - registering flush begin
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - Inserting entity: [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032673]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - Version: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 1)
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] SQL: - insert into timeseries (calc_type, channel_id, counts, data_value, granularity, highest_valid_data_time, max_value, min_value, series_end_time, series_start_time, version, series_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - preparing statement
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - Dehydrating entity: [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032673]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] LongType: - binding '52283' to parameter: 2
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] IntegerType: - binding '0' to parameter: 11
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] LongType: - binding '188032673' to parameter: 12
2011-03-31 14:20:37,419 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - Inserting entity: [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032674]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,420 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractEntityPersister: - Version: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,420 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - reusing prepared statement
2011-03-31 14:20:37,420 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] SQL: - insert into timeseries (calc_type, channel_id, counts, data_value, granularity, highest_valid_data_time, max_value, min_value, series_end_time, series_start_time, version, series_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
//snip

2011-03-31 14:20:37,478 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - Executing batch size: 50
2011-03-31 14:20:37,506 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - no batched statements to execute
2011-03-31 14:20:37,506 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 2)
2011-03-31 14:20:37,506 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractBatcher: - closing statement
2011-03-31 14:20:37,506 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] ConnectionManager: - registering flush end
2011-03-31 14:20:37,506 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener: - post flush
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] VersionValue: - version unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] IdentifierValue: - id unsaved-value: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - transient instance of: com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] DefaultPersistEventListener: - saving transient instance
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - generated identifier: 188032723, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - saving [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032723]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] Versioning: - using initial version: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] VersionValue: - version unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] IdentifierValue: - id unsaved-value: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - transient instance of: com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] DefaultPersistEventListener: - saving transient instance
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 DEBUG [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - generated identifier: 188032724, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractSaveEventListener: - saving [com.xxx.TimeSeriesEntity#188032724]
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] Versioning: - using initial version: 0
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] VersionValue: - version unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
2011-03-31 14:20:37,507 TRACE [pool-2-thread-3] IdentifierValue: - id unsaved-value: 0

Here is the session factory init:

2011-03-31 14:16:17,521  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider: - Using provided datasource
2011-03-31 14:16:17,535  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - RDBMS: PostgreSQL, version: 9.0.2
2011-03-31 14:16:17,535  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - JDBC driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 801)
2011-03-31 14:16:17,560  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] Dialect: - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2011-03-31 14:16:17,564  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] TransactionFactoryFactory: - Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
2011-03-31 14:16:17,564  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] TransactionManagerLookupFactory: - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - JDBC batch size: 50
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Scrollable result sets: enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565 DEBUG [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Wrap result sets: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,565  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Connection release mode: auto
2011-03-31 14:16:17,566  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Default batch fetch size: 1
2011-03-31 14:16:17,566  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,566  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Order SQL updates by primary key: enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,566  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Order SQL inserts for batching: enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,566  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2011-03-31 14:16:17,567  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] ASTQueryTranslatorFactory: - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2011-03-31 14:16:17,567  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Query language substitutions: {}
2011-03-31 14:16:17,567  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,567  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Second-level cache: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,567  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Query cache: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,567  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
2011-03-31 14:16:17,568  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,568  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Structured second-level cache entries: enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,568 TRACE [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SQLExceptionConverterFactory: - Using dialect defined converter
2011-03-31 14:16:17,570  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Statistics: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,570  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,571  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Default entity-mode: pojo
2011-03-31 14:16:17,571  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SettingsFactory: - Named query checking : enabled
2011-03-31 14:16:17,589  INFO [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SessionFactoryImpl: - building session factory
2011-03-31 14:16:17,590 DEBUG [SpringOsgiExtenderThread-46] SessionFactoryImpl: - Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses batch inserts. This does not mean that a single statement is used to insert many entities. It means it uses [`Statement.addBatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) and `Statement.executeBatch()` internally. This effectively reduces the number of roadtrips to the database (read the linked javadoc for more detailed explanations), and I very much doubt it's less (or significantly less) performant than a single insert statement.

Before optimizing, make sure there is a performance problem, and make sure to spot where the performance problem comes from.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true. I see a lot of evidence that it should do that: http://sensiblerationalization.blogspot.com/2011/03/quick-tip-on-hibernate-batch-operation.html  or here http://abramsm.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/hibernate-batch-processing-why-you-may-not-be-using-it-even-if-you-think-you-are/

Comment: Or this from the hibernate forum:   or  https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2374413

Comment: Read the official documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional : "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size : A non-zero value enables use of JDBC2 batch updates by Hibernate. e.g. recommended values between 5 and 30 ". And then read what JDBC2 batch updates are in the official documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html

Comment: Also: read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch for how to optimize batch inserts.